# How is this related to continuity?

Tags: calculus, continuity

This problem is surprisingly in the continuity exercises in my textbook. 
I have made a little progress with proving it to be less or equal to 1 but that's all.

$n \in \Bbb{N} \setminus \{0,1\}$, $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in [0,1]$.

Prove that:

$$ \exists \alpha \in [0,1] \ : \ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}|\alpha -a_n | = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: Use this link to type your question in Math Stack Exchange https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

For $\alpha =0$, $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|\alpha-a_k|=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k},$$
whereas for $\alpha =1$, $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|\alpha-a_k|=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-a_k)=1-\color{blue}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Do the following things:

1. Prove that the function
   $$f:\alpha\in[0,1]\longmapsto\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|\alpha-a_n|$$
   is continuous
2. Show that you must have $f(0)\le\frac{1}{2}\le f(1)$ or $f(0)\ge\frac{1}{2}\ge f(1)$.
3. Conclude.